# Cloudfront, files from member area

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently testing amazon cloudfront, it seems to be a nice cdn tool.
Btw, I see the cdn handle the file from the "public area" but it there a way to store files only available in a member area ? Only files like css, js (...) that we don't need to protect but only loaded in member area?

Thanks.

Comment: They don't "need protection" so, sure, as long as your app doesn't require authentication. In fact, cloudfront can pass parameters and cookies, which means it can handle authenticated bits too. If you want more specific information you will need to post more details- site organization, language/framework, what you've tried, etc.

Comment: Ok I didn't try anything for the member area as I didn't find if cloudfront can handle this. I am using cakephp mvc ; in order to access to the member area , it's a username/password POST form. Behind the member area is handled by a session in order to check if the user can access or not to a page.

Comment: why not move the CSS and other static assets outside of the auth'd area?

Comment: I can but how cloudfront will access the files, as I have a directory Options -Indexes in the css, js folders ? It cannot see the files not loaded on the public area.

Comment: you don't want cloudfront to "index" them. Your page will request static CSS/JS, and cloudfront will request and cache it from your server. This question needs to be answered in chat with someone, there are a lot of fundamental problems, not a simple answer.

Comment: Are you free for a chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69081/discussion-between-zeflex-and-tedder42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about serving private CloudFront content to your member, but not to public ?

If yes, AWS supports that in CloudFront.

But you need to do either "signed url" or "signed cookie" method to access the cloudfront assets.  ( of course, you need to setup your cloudfront and S3 )

1. Signed URL means URL will have query string with signed auth parameters.
2. Signed Cookie means those signed auth parameters are save in cookies.

And AWS also support custom policy if you have very complicated policy for your CDN.

You can access this link for more info

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-cloudfront.html